How would I loop through characters in elements, held in a list?
(This is just a section of code):

Please turn off "smart quotes" when posting code here. All your quotes in the code are wrong.

[i][1] should be i[1]. Also, remember that list indexes start at 0, not 1.

Each time through the loop you overwrite position. At the end you'll just have the value for the last element of binary.

And if an element has multiple bits set, like 0101, you'll set position to the last one. You need to rethink what you're doing here.

In Chrome, it's Edit->Substitutions->Smart Quotes.

It doesn't matter what variable you set, you'll still overwrite it each time through the loop. It's not clear what this is really supposed to be doing. If you need information about a specific cell, you should just do that cell, not loop over all cells in the file.

What you probably want is a function that takes the coordinates of a square and a direction, and returns True or False depending on whether you can move that direction from the square.

Sorry, I don't know how to get the Edit menu in mobile browsers. It's best to use a PC when posting to SO.

In the code:
    for i in binary:
        if [i][1] == ‘1’:
            position = “west”


[i] is a single-element list.
[i][1] attempts to access the second element of that single-element list.
Because single-element lists don't have a second element, the expression [i][1] will inevitably fail.
The highest (and lowest) valid index for a single-element array is 0.

As per Barmar's second post, removing the square brackets is likely to fix the problem. If not, you need to debug to find out what the values of i are.
It could also be useful to add some length-checking to be sure that each value of i is adequately long.

Problems in this code:

You tried to use [i][1] to get a character from a string inside a list. This is incorrect because it looks like you're trying to use i as if it's already a string, but it's meant to be an index (a number telling the position of something in the list).
lines like "none" == 4 don't do anything useful. They just compare a word to a number, which won't change or set any values.
You missed some colons (:) and quotes in your if statements

To fix:
def set_directions(binary):
  directions_list = []
    for binary_string in binary: 
      position = []
      if len(binary_string) > 1 and binary_string[1] == '1':
         position.append("west")
      if len(binary_string) > 2 and binary_string[2] == '1':
         position.append("south")
      if len(binary_string) > 3 and binary_string[3] == '1':
         position.append("east")
      if len(binary_string) > 4 and binary_string[4] == '1':
         position.append("north")
      else: 
         position.append(0)
      directions_list.append(position)
   return directions_list
        


It is not clear what you want to do to me exactly, but maybe this will help you get started:
def get_directions(binary):
    directions = []
    if binary[0] == '1':
        directions.append("west")
    if binary[1] == '1':
        directions.append("south")
    if binary[2] == '1':
        directions.append("east")
    if binary[3] == '1':
        directions.append("north")
    return directions

numbers = ['0101','1011','0010'] # some test numbers
for binary in numbers:
    directions = get_directions(binary)
    print('directions:', directions)

output:
directions: ['south', 'north']
directions: ['west', 'east', 'north']
directions: ['east']

Split your problem into smaller parts. Solve one part at the time. Print some test data to check that it works correctly, fix if necessary. Only then move to the next part.
